# $_GET Loading Elements/Data From Another Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]

I have a page that shoots over to a script, loads my elements and data, then comes back. The problem being that `?name=steve` obviously doesn't make the transition from scripts.php to load.php. How am I able to use `$name = $_GET['name'];` in `load.php`? Also is this code below bad? I was told that this is over complicating it.

```
function showInfo(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("rankhint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("rankhint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                $(document).foundation();
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or save name in session.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the query string through to the next page.

Assign it to a variable and then append to the URL:

```
var qs = "<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>";
xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?"+qs+"&q="+str,true);
```

Comment: You can get your query string in JavaScript using something like:
`var qs = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("?")+1);`